401 Unauthorized response when fetching an embed token for Power BI
I followed the article listed here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal
I then wrote a C# console application that first generates an access token and then generates an embed token using the Power BI Nuget library method GetReportInGroupAsync
However, this method throws an Unauthorized error. I printed the response data and saw the following header;
X-PowerBI-Error-Info: ServicePrincipalIsNotAllowedByTenantAdminSwitch
My Power BI admin has already enabled this setting in the Power BI Admin Portal and the security group that contains my service principal is added to the list of groups for which access is allowed.
What am I missing?

I resolved this by removing the Azure AD group from Power BI and then adding it again. I raised a ticket with Microsoft and this is how we solved it

This error usually happens when the service account isn't allowed to use Power BI resources or hasn't been given the right APIs permissions to do so.
If you enable the settings for “allow the Service Principal to use Power BI APIs”, then verify that the Service Principal is added to the workspace by checking the workspace access settings.
After this, ensure that your Azure Active Directory application linked to your Service Principal has the necessary API permissions (such as Reports.Read.All, Dataset.Read.All, etc.) in the Azure portal.
To verify these permissions:

Navigate to Azure Active Directory.
Go to "App registrations" and select your application.
Click on "API permissions" to view the granted permissions.
If the required permissions are missing, click "Add a permission" > "Microsoft APIs" > "Power BI Service."
Select the necessary permissions and click "Add permissions."
Click "Grant admin consent for your application."

You can refer to this documentation:
Embed content in your Power BI embedded analytics application - Power BI | Microsoft Learn
